# Maya Swap object X & Z axis

Tags: python, pivot, alignment, maya

I`m working on script for Maya which should align object pivot forwards selected target. But what I have is Z axis is pointed to target insted of X axis. This by default.

My workflow is:

```
#getting direction
vector = target postition - object position and apply it to objects pivot

# getting vector rotation values
vectorOrientation = cmds.angleBetween(euler=True, v1=(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), v2=vector, ch=0)

cmds.select(ObjectWhitchPivotShouldBeAlighned)

# applying vector to object pivot
cmds.manipPivot(o=vector)
```

It works but I have unwanted axis.

**Here are decisions which solve problem.**

A) Change code a little bit

```
  # don`t understand how but it works
  vectorOrientation = cmds.angleBetween(euler=True, v1=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), v2=vector, ch=0)
```

B)

- Create dummy(locator)
- Align locator to object(position/rotation)
- Rotate locator in object space so the X axis is pointed forward target
- Transfer locator rotation values to object pivot via cmds.manipPivot(o=[float,float,float])

Maybe somebody can advise more proper and clean solutions.
All opinions are appreciated